# spidev / Python error

Tags: python, spi

```
import spidev
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 1)
l = ['0x20','0x01','0x00','0x10','0x3D','0x04','0x00','0x05','0x00','0x01','0x00','0x00','0x00','0x00','0x00','0x00','0x00','0x00','0x00','0x00'] 
resp = spi.xfer2(l)
```

results in:

> TypeError: Non-Int/Long value in arguments: b592da58.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're passing in a list of strings and it expects ints - you want:

```
import spidev
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 1)
l = [0x20,0x01,0x00,0x10,0x3D,0x04,0x00,0x05,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00] 
resp = spi.xfer2(l)
```